# Links to generated posts are all broken in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

When I am going through the linked documents it is saying 401 unauthorized. How to fix this issue?

It shows like this in the terminal:

> "HTTP request sent, awaiting response ... 401 unauthorized"

Comment: Where are the linked documents , can you share more details ?

Comment: I have shared this document with my supervisor but now it's not opening as well.   https://git.hb.dfki.de/uploads/bc8bfbd65c47df68093abde35fd2c2a5/Proposal_doc.odt

Comment: I have no idea how to deal with this problem now. All those things were working perfectly but now all the links are broken. There should be something to recover all of them. https://git.hb.dfki.de/uploads/df88a9f909c267a4b72cfc07873e7bfa/MasterProjectDescription_Dominguez_Illumination.pdf

Answer (score 0):

These look like files uploaded to an issue, merge request, comment, etc. You are only able to access those files within the context of the issue, merge request, comment where they were originally posted. This is a security measure as you wouldn't want these files to be accessible to someone who wasn't a part of your project, or if the issue was confidential, etc. Instead you should either give the issue/merge request link to the person you wish to share with, or you should download the file and send through other means.